# How to implement promises in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I made this project based on a YT tutorial but adding some extra features
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdWHF.png)
the problem I have is the following, this is the code that is used to show the data of the database

```
controller.list = (req, res) => {
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ", (err, usuarios) => {
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }
        res.render("usuarios", {
            data: usuarios
        })
    })
})
```

}

but I don't know how to modify it so that in the part that says "usado" it shows me the number of times that the "Codigo" is repeated. I know that with a MySQL query similar to this one 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS namesCount FROM names WHERE age = ?' I can show the number of times it repeats, but I don't know how to implement this in the controller, I know I can do it with promises but I don't know how to modify the code to implement it.

Comment: Sounds like this is more of a MySQL query problem rather than a promises one? I.e. "for each row, I would like a number which is a sum of some other set of rows".

Comment: yes, the problem is that I don't know how to do 2 queries in the same controller

Comment: The most straight forward way is a nested query `conn.query(query1, (e, u) => { /* error checks */ conn.query(query2, (e, c) => { /* error checks and render */ }); })`. IMHO a better approach is to use a promisified API and to await the queries.